# arduino create online ide not working, loading indefinitely

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Mega 2560 microcontroller. It was working fine excellently, until about two days ago when I dual booted with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my windows 10 laptop. Since then the online Arduino create IDE has problems uploading code to my microcontroller...
gives me this error every time, even on the desktop IDE. I have been looking for a solution for a long time now, nothing has worked.

```
Sketch uses 2812 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.

Global variables use 67 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 8125 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.

Programming with: Serial

Flashing with command:/home/sai/.arduino-create/arduino/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14/bin/avrdude -C/home/sai/.arduino-create/arduino/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cwiring -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino-create-agent634272836/lcd_and_ultrasonic.hex:i

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130

Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

System wide configuration file is "/home/sai/.arduino-create/arduino/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino14/etc/avrdude.conf"

User configuration file is "/home/sai/.avrduderc"

User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

Using Port : /dev/ttyACM0

Using Programmer : wiring

Overriding Baud Rate : 115200

avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied

ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: I'm running the ide on chrome btw

Comment: That didn't work but I was prompted automatically later when I was using the desktop ide. Then it started working

Answer (score 0):

The following line tells you the problem:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
```

The canonical way of gaining read/write permissions for serial devices is becoming member of the `dialout` group.

Assuming your username is `sai` and you are running the IDE/browser as that user, the command to add that user to the `dialout` group is:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout sai
```

You need to logout and back in for the changes to take effect.